# Dynamic variable value?

Tags: perl

perl code:

```
my %config = (
    randValue => int(rand(10)),
);

print $config{ randValue }."\n";
print $config{ randValue }."\n";
```

will produce:

```
8
8
```

Is it possible to get different value each time? (execute `int(rand(10))` each time the `$config{ randValue }` is called)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either use [tied hash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html#Tying-Hashes), or function:

```
my %config = (
    randValue => sub { int(rand(10)) },
);

print $config{randValue}->();
print $config{randValue}->();
```

Comment: You can use *magic* or a sub. `tie` is just one kind of magic. `use Variable::Magic qw( wizard cast ); cast(my $d10, wizard( get => sub { ${$_[0]} = int(rand(10))+1 } ));` I recommend using a sub.

Comment: I just burst into laughter in the office reading that documentation: "a 'wizard', an opaque object that holds the magic information" and "Note that free magic is never called during global destruction" both awesome citations in any fantasy setting and "If you define a wizard with free magic and cast it on itself, it results in a memory cycle, so this destructor will not be called when the wizard is freed." sounds like the backstory to an epic quest.